# Using Index Match to get the Desired Result from the Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been striving hard to make a formula which match the dates and populate the index.

I have created this formula but if there are more then similar two dates or three or more in the data then how the data for all the similar dates will be populated in the cell.

I have attached a sheet where 1st Table has Data, 2nd is my table where i have applied below formula and third table is the accurate example the result i have been looking for.

Your help will be appreciated.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C2:C92,MATCH(F3,A2:A92,0)))
```

Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WT7MJuNqspJGU6wLtKQRp2BxpuiRknkEKfZR4MZd-0A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You link to a google sheet. Google sheets are not Excel

Comment: This is just for an example @FunThomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365 then in cell `F3` put:

`=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$92=E3,$C$2:$C$92,""))`

and in cell `G3` put:

`=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$92=E3,($B$2:$B$92*100)&"%",""))`

Please note that percentage is not actual percentage but a concatenated string in the output formula.

**EDIT**

You can try below UDF if you don't have `TEXTJOIN`

```
Public Function ConcatStringConditional(rngCritCol As Range, rngCrit As Range, rngConcat As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rngCritCol.Cells.Count
        If rngCritCol.Cells(i, 1).Value2 = rngCrit.Value2 Then
            If Len(ConcatStringConditional) > 0 Then
                ConcatStringConditional = ConcatStringConditional & vbCrLf & Format(rngConcat.Cells(i, 1).Value, rngConcat.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat)
            Else
                ConcatStringConditional = Format(rngConcat.Cells(i, 1).Value, rngConcat.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

This shall be copied to a module in Visual Basic Editor by choosing `Insert|Module`. You can google to see the procedure if you are unsure. Once put in a module then it can be used like a normal formula e.g.

`=ConcatStringConditional($A$2:$A$92,E4,$C$2:$C$92)`

This is basic functionality, please feel free to edit to your requirements further.

**Note:** Macros must be enabled for the UDF to run properly!

Comment: Thank you but i have been using Office 2016.

Comment: @Mento in absence of `TEXTJOIN`, I can suggest using a VBA User Defined Function. Are you okay with that option?

Comment: Yes i would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next UDF function. It uses array and will be very fast, for big ranges:

```
Function bringData(D As Range, Optional X As String) As String
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, lastR As Long, i As Long, strD As String
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastR).value
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If CDate(arr(i, 1)) = CDate(D.value) Then
        strD = strD & IIf(X = "D", arr(i, 3), arr(i, 2) * 100 & "%") & vbLf
    End If
  Next i
  If strD <> "" Then
    strD = left(strD, Len(strD) - 1)
    bringData = strD
  Else
    bringData = "No Match"
  End If
End Function
```

It can be called in the next way:

To obtain the Data (per date) the formula will be:

```
=bringData(E2,"D")
```

In order to bring the percentage, the formula should be:

```
=bringData(E2)
```

The above code assumes that the first Table is in the range "A:C" and the the second one in the range "E:G", starting from the second row...

If in different ranges, the code should be easy to adapt, I think. If not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask.

Please, test it and send some feedback.

**Edited**:

Try the next code for the three options. Use "D", "D2" or nothing like the second function parameter:

```
Function bringData(D As Range, Optional X As String) As String
  Dim Sh As Worksheet, arr, lastR As Long, i As Long, strD As String
  
  Set Sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = Sh.Range("A" & Sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = Sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).value
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If CDate(arr(i, 1)) = CDate(D.value) Then
        strD = strD & IIf(X = "D", arr(i, 3), IIf(X = "D2", arr(i, 4), arr(i, 2) * 100 & "%")) & vbLf
    End If
  Next i
  If strD <> "" Then
    strD = left(strD, Len(strD) - 1)
    bringData = strD
  Else
    bringData = "No Match"
  End If
End Function
```

I will be available only after 3 - 4 hours...

Comment: Thank you very much @FaneDuru for the Arrays solution.

Comment: What if i want to match two criteria @FaneDuru please look into the attached sheet.

Comment: @Mento: Do you mean, also bringing 'Persons' from column D:D? Should I also understand that you did not need bringing of percentages?

Comment: Yes in that case code will match 2 values first is date then person then result will be populated. Same matching criteria will be applied for populating the percentage

Comment: @Mento: I am afraid you did not understand the function... It has to be differently called for matching whatever you want. Did you test the above code? If yes, did you test it for percentages, too?

Comment: I must leave my office. I will post an updated code which should do what you need. Not tested (percentages may be all on the same row). I can do something in some hour, when I will be at home...

Comment: No yet but now started testing it but confused that why its not working because i am unable to change the Range(E:G)  can you please share how to change the range

Comment: Alright, I have been waiting for the updated code. Thanks

Comment: @Mento: If you mean to adapt the formula, you simple must choose the column where the data to be searched exists... Now I am leaving.

Comment: @Mento Now, I am at home. Didn't you make it working?

Comment: I have tried it but really don't understand how to use it. @FaneDuru the problem is that how to get the desired result through the UDF formula

Comment: @Mento But, it should be obvious... You can put the formula wherever you need! The first function parameter must be a cell having the date to be searched, and the second is "D" to return Date1 and "D2" to return Date2. Without the second parameter, it will return the percentage. If still not clear, can you share your workbook? I will show you on it how to use the function...

Comment: It will be huge help. let me prepare the workbook will share it within 2 to 3 minutes

Comment: attached a sheet link in the post that is Updated XL file @FaneDuru

Comment: @Mento I cannot download your workbook. Please, use [this](https://easyupload.io/) transfer site. It is free and easy to be used.

Comment: This site is not getting open. Error is > Error 1020 
Access denied

Comment: @Mento it should be accessible. Please, try opening it again... If it stil does not work, try [this one](http://s000.tinyupload.com/). If not working, too, I am afraid I cannot help you. It is a matter of wrong security settings on your computer.

Comment: @Mento I downloaded the file, but I do not understand what you need doing. Where would you like to return and from where? The file structure is completely different from the one we could see. And where is my function code?

Comment: @Mento Did you download the workbook I sent? Do not the formulas **I placed there** work as you need? Did you look at them?

Comment: Yes downloaded and using it the third table should be like IF i want to look for the data of "Person B" then only person B data will be populated not for all.

Comment: @Mento Where from to take another person if the searched date **exists only one time**? Sorry, it is late in my country and it looks I am wasting my time. I whish you a gook night!

Comment: The person can be placed in "EY1" Thank you for the help you provided. I really appreciate.